# Spring -XD Stream deployment failure

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am trying to deploy two spring-XD streams. Stream 1 and Stream 2. Both the streams are getting deployed fine in the local box (Single node) but when i try to deploy this in higher environment (distributed node) Stream 2 is getting deployed successfully but not stream 1.

Here is the Stream Definition

Stream --name test definition "CustomSource | Custom Processor 1 | Custom Processor 2 | Custom Processor 3 > queue:TestQueue"

Below is the error I am seeing in the admin logs.
I believe this is thrown from the spring-xd framework and not sure how to overcome this.

> DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'objectNameProperties' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence' in string value "${xd.module.sequence}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence' in string value "${xd.module.sequence}"
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)

Comment: What version of XD? Exactly what topology? (standalone, yarn, etc; how many containers?). Show your stream definitions; post a DEBUG log from the container where the deployment is failing (enable DEBUG logging for all of `org.springframework`). The log will be too big for here, so post in a github gist, pastebin, etc, etc.

Comment: xd version spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE. Its a distributed mode with 1 admin and 3 containers. I am not able to enable debug mode since this is a multi-tenant environment and it requires a restart and the existing streams will be impacted. However we tried distributed mode in local machin to see if we can recreate the error and enable debug but it didnt fail in local machine. Updated the Question with Stream Definition

Answer (score 1):

There's something awry with that container instance; that property has been around since version 1.1. It's used to indicate which instance of the module this is.

Even if deployed with `count=0`, it gets set to `0`.

Which module is failing? What deployment properties are you using?

You may have to bounce the container.

Comment: CustomSource is failing  stream deploy CustomSource  deploymentcount =1

Comment: Someone else reported the same problem; I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3727).